# Перенос из одной таблицу в другую при обновлении

Tags: sql-server

у меня есть вот такая таблица в MS SQL

```
ITEM_ID INT IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL
CONSTRAINT PK_Item PRIMARY KEY,   
Name          NVARCHAR(50)       NOT NULL,
Price         FLOAT              NOT NULL,
PriceToReturn FLOAT              NOT NULL,
Discription   NVARCHAR(120)      NOT NULL,
PS            NVARCHAR(120)      NOT NULL,
Returned      BIT                NOT NULL,
```

Мне нужно написать триггер который при обновлении поля "Returned" перенесёт обновлённую строку в другую, точно такую же таблицу, задача элементарная как мне кажется, но мне нужна помощь

Comment: использовать триггер AFTER UPDATE. можете ознакомиться: https://metanit.com/sql/sqlserver/12.2.php

Answer (score 0):

Решение проблемы

```
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER Returned
ON Item
AFTER UPDATE
AS
    BEGIN
        IF UPDATE(Returned)
        BEGIN
        DECLARE @Name NVARCHAR(40)
        DECLARE @Price FLOAT
        DECLARE @PriceToReturn FLOAT
        DECLARE @Discription NVARCHAR(40)
        DECLARE @PS NVARCHAR(120)
        SET @Name = (SELECT Name FROM deleted)
        SET @Price = (SELECT Price FROM deleted)
        SET @PriceToReturn = (SELECT PriceToReturn FROM deleted)
        SET @Discription = (SELECT Discription FROM deleted)
        SET @PS = (SELECT PS FROM deleted)
        INSERT INTO ReturnedItems(Name, Price, PriceToReturn, Discription, PS) VALUES(@Name,@Price,@PriceToReturn,@Discription,@PS)
    END;
END;
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: а если будет вставка нескольких строк?